# Meteor windows exception in future.js

Tags: windows, exception, meteor, undefined, future

My meteor application is crashing. I have already deleted as much code as possible and it still throws the exception. When I start a new app, then it does not throw any error, but the exception is in the instalation file. Any ideas?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:206
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend.runTask (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:78:9)
    at _.extend._addFirstObserveHandle (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:740:21)
    at _Mongo._observeChanges (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:599:20)
    at Cursor.observeChanges (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:422:22)
    at Cursor._publishCursor (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:387:28)
    at _.extend._runHandler (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:859:11)
    at _.extend._startSubscription (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:724:9)
    at _.extend.startUniversalSubs (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:367:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    - - - - -
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:323:16)
    at _Mongo._getCollection (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:137:17)
    at _Mongo._createSynchronousCursor (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:430:25)
    at _.extend._pollMongo (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:805:51)
    at Object._.extend._addFirstObserveHandle [as task] (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:741:12)
    at _.extend._run (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:143:18)
    at _.extend._scheduleRun (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:121:14)
    - - - - -
    at Db.collection (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\packages\mongo-livedata\.npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mong
odb\db.js:452:24)
    at _Mongo._getCollection (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:132:13)
    at _Mongo._createSynchronousCursor (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:430:25)
    at _.extend._pollMongo (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:805:51)
    at Object._.extend._addFirstObserveHandle [as task] (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:741:12)
    at _.extend._run (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:143:18)
    at _.extend._scheduleRun (app/packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:121:14)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted
```

Comment: It seems that the exception is thrown when trying to define an object collection in the server:
var ocWorkspaces = new Meteor.Collection('workspaces');

Comment: I'm able to execute that line on the server without problem. Can you make the cut down app available somewhere? Have you tried to deploy it temporarily to meteor.com to see if it is Windows or a general issue? Could you add some console.log() statements to try to pin down exactly what is undefined.  Unfortunately, the combination of javascript callbacks and fibers/futures makes stack traces a black art.

Comment: I reinstalled Meteor and now works fine. Thanks

Comment: man, had same error a week ago on my Mac, so it's not Windows specific. The problem was, something was throwing an exception inside the added callback, if you still care and can post the repro,  maybe we can fight it!